# How can I detect if a member changed the nickname of a other member in JDA?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I want to make a Server Log feature, where stuff like messages changes, roles and nickname changes should be logged.

What I had done yet was this:

```java
@Override
    public void onGuildMemberUpdateNickname(@NotNull GuildMemberUpdateNicknameEvent event) {
        if(BotMain.getInstance().getSettings().serverLogChannel != -1) {
            TextChannel serverlog = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById(BotMain.getInstance().getSettings().serverLogChannel);
            boolean removed = event.getNewNickname() == null;
            boolean created = event.getOldNickname() == null;
            EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
            if(removed) {
                builder.setColor(Color.RED);
                builder.setAuthor("Nickname entfernt", event.getEntity().getUser().getAvatarUrl(), event.getEntity().getUser().getAvatarUrl());
                builder.addField("Änderung", event.getOldNickname() + " \u279C " + event.getEntity().getUser().getName(), false);
                builder.addField("Betrifft", event.getEntity().getAsMention(), false);
                builder.addField("Geändert von", event.getMember().getAsMention(), false);
            } else if(created) {
                builder.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                builder.setAuthor("Nickname erstellt", event.getEntity().getUser().getAvatarUrl(), event.getEntity().getUser().getAvatarUrl());
                builder.addField("Änderung", event.getEntity().getUser().getName() + " \u279C " + event.getNewNickname(), false);
                builder.addField("Betrifft", event.getEntity().getAsMention(), false);
                builder.addField("Geändert von", event.getMember().getAsMention(), false);
            } else {
                builder.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                builder.setAuthor("Nickname geändert", event.getEntity().getUser().getAvatarUrl(), event.getEntity().getUser().getAvatarUrl());
                builder.addField("Änderung", event.getOldNickname() + " \u279C " + event.getNewNickname(), false);
                builder.addField("Betrifft", event.getEntity().getAsMention(), false);
                builder.addField("Geändert von", event.getMember().getAsMention(), false);
            }
            serverlog.sendMessage(builder.build()).queue();
        }
    }
```

But that's only triggered when a member changes his nickname, but not if a member changes the nickname of a other member.

Is there a possibility to detect this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this event GenericGuildMemberUpdateEvent ([GenericGuildMemberUpdateEvent](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/guild/member/update/GenericGuildMemberUpdateEvent.html)) and the following methods :

- getEntity() (to get the affected entity, the Member in your case)
- getMember() (to get the affector, the guy who changed the name, herited from [GenericGuildMemberEvent](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/guild/member/GenericGuildMemberEvent.html))
- getPropertyIdentifier() (to get the property name, might be nickname or something)
- getNewValue() and getOldValue() (to get the old and new nickname)

I cannot verify this right now, keep me informed.

Comment: It's like `onGuildMemberUpdateNickname` only fired, when you change your own nickname

Comment: I did not understand, sorry